# Removing Comma from xml

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am trying to replace comma with single space  from my XML using xslt 1.0 / xslt 2.0. 
Please help, Thanks in advance.

**Using XML**

```
<Root>
    <Master>
        <Worker_group>
            <Emp_ID>1001</Emp_ID>
            <E_Name>Worker1 , Jr </E_Name>
            <Line1>2001 Mark ST,</LINE1>
            <Line2>Building 2, Apt 101</LINE1> 
            <City> XYZ </City>
            <state>NC</State>
         </Worker_group>
    </Master>
    <Master>
        <Worker_group>
            <Emp_ID>1002</Emp_ID>
            <E_Name>Worker2 , Sr</E_Name>
            <Line1>1001 STACY ST,</LINE1>
            <Line2>Building 11, Apt 112</LINE1> 
            <City> ABC </City>
            <state>FL</State>
        </Worker_group>
        <Dependents_group>
            <Dep_Emp_ID>1001</Dep_Emp_ID>
            <D_Name>Dependent1, </D_Name>
            <D_Line1>1001 STACY ST,</D_LINE1>
            <D_Line2>Building 11, Apt 112</D_LINE2> 
            <D_City> ABC </D_City>
            <D_state>FL</D_State>
        </Dependents_group>
        <Dependents_group>
            <Dep_Emp_ID>1001</Dep_Emp_ID>
            <D_Name>Dependent2 </D_Name>
            <D_Line1>1001 STACY ST,</LINE1>
            <D_Line2>Building 11, Apt 112</D_LINE2> 
            <D_City> ABC </D_City>
            <D_state>FL</D_State>
        </Dependents_group>
        <Dependents_group>
            <Dep_Emp_ID>1001</Dep_Emp_ID>
            <D_Name>Dependent3 , Mr </D_Name>
            <D_Line1>1001 STACY ST,</D_LINE1>
            <D_Line2>Building 11, Apt 112</D_LINE2> 
            <D_City> ABC </D_City>
            <D_state>FL</D_State>
        </Dependents_group>
    </Master>
    <Master>
        <Worker_group>
            <Emp_ID>1003</Emp_ID>
            <E_Name>Worker3, </E_Name>
            <Line1>11 Hide ST</LINE1>
            <Line2>Apt 234,</LINE1> 
            <City> ABC, </City>
            <state>SC</State>
        </Worker_group>
    </Master>
</Root>
```

**using XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>id,relationship,Name&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Master/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="Emp_ID | Dep_Emp_ID"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:number count="*"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="E_Name | D_Name"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Line1 | D_Line1"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Line2 | D_Line2"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="City | D_City"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="State | D_State"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
id,relationship,Name,Line1,Line2,City,State
1001,1,Worker1 Jr,2001 Mark ST,Building 2 Apt 101,XYZ,NC
1002,1,Worker2 Sr,1001 STACY ST,Building 11 Apt 112,ABC,FL
1001,2,Dependent1,1001 STACY ST,Building 11 Apt 112,ABC,FL
1001,3,Dependent2,1001 STACY ST,Building 11 Apt 112,ABC,FL
1001,4,Dependent3 Mr,1001 STACY ST,Building 11 Apt 112,ABC,FL
1003,1,Worker3,11 Hide St,Apt 234,ABC,Sc
```

Comment: The XML in your question is not well-formed: `<Line1>` does not match `</LINE1>` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `translate` function.
Substitute the `,` with any char.  Also, you can replace the '.' with any node.

```
translate(.,',', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<xsl:value-of select="E_Name | D_Name"/>
```

with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(E_Name | D_Name, ',', ' '))"/>
```

and so on for the other data cells.